# Span tag inside the asp text box is not working in Firefox

Tags: asp.net

I am able to generate some  tags inside the asp textbox control using jquery
Following is the jquery

```
var bb = document.createElement('span');
   bb.innerHTML= "test123";
   $("#" + "<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").append(bb);
```

I can see the text "test123" in IE but a blank textbox in Firefox(I am using 5).

When I see in firebug, that span got create inside the textbox.

Can anyone tell me how to make that span content to be displayed/get shown in FF too?

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this problem before ::

Essentially .append operation is adding the span into   . Changes to this are not always reflected in Chrome/Firefox .

Instead try adding it by using

```
TextBox.value += "Testing content addition";
```

Comment: I know this is a javascript function. But I need a SPAN tag inside that textbox. If I give one tag, it shows the "<span>test123</span>" as it is. Not just "test123". The reason why I need this is I need to format only some text inside the textbox.